# Software to help planning a course

Tags: teaching, lecture-teaching-method, course-design

I’m teaching a few classes next semester and feel scattered. Can you recommend some software to help me plan out a course so on each day I can see what topic I’m teaching, activities planned, homework to assign etc? Would be great to have a nice overview though I could just use excel too if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of software to do this. First, check with your institution because they might already have one. This can totally depend on where you are but in the US, Canvas is very popular, but I believe you need institution or individual subscription for that. Google classroom is another cool solution which is free of cost. Both these are good and kind of widespread. Other than these there are countless number of software that you can find, and they all have their pros and cons.